# union type inference in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type p1 = { a: number, b: string }
type p3 = { a: string }
type p4 = p1 | p3

let demo: p4 = { a: '123', b: '123' }

function isP3(obj: p4): obj is p3 { 
    return typeof (<p3>obj).a === 'string'
}

function func(obj: p4) {
    if ('b' in obj) {
        // Uncaught TypeError: obj.a.toFixed is not a function
        obj.a.toFixed() //<- Now, no error is given
    } else { 

    }
}
func(demo)
```

Why the demo did not report an error when initialize?
User-Defined Type Guards

Comment: You likely want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). And why are you asking *us* what something will be inferred to be? Check in your editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open issue (microsoft/TypeScript#20863)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863) in TypeScript.  Your union type is not a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), so the compiler doesn't split the union up into members before performing [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  Most people (myself included) would expect that excess property checks should occur for each member of the union whether or not the union is a discriminated one.  For now, though, that's just the way it is: the compiler sees that `"b"` is an acceptable property in at least one of the union members and decides not to complain.

Note that excess property checking is a convenience, and not a matter of type safety.  Object types in TypeScript are *open*, and you can always add more properties to them over what's in the definition without violating the type.  A value `{x: 1, y: 2}` is a valid `{x: number}` despite having that `y` property.  Another way of saying this is that object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  It is therefore technically true that `{ a: '123', b: '123' }` is a valid `p3` and therefore a valid `p4`.  And so, technically, you can't just check for the presence or absence of `b` to distinguish between `p1` and `p3`.  Yes, if you just try to say `const demo: p3 = {a: '123', b: '123'}` you'll get an excess property warning on `"b"`, but this is, as I said, just a convenience.  It is easily defeated:

```
const demo1 = { a: '123', b: '123' };
const demo2: p3 = demo1; // no error
```

---

At this point you might be wondering: "wait, if `"b"` does not properly distinguish `p1` from `p3`, why does the compiler think it does inside `func()`?".  Good question:

```
if ('b' in obj) { // why does the compiler think this narrows obj to p1?
    obj.a.toFixed() // no error, but blows up at runtime
}
```

Well, it turns out that [the `in` type guard is intentionally unsound](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152).  It's technically not safe to use it, but people do and usually it's not a problem.  But it doesn't help you here.  Oh well.

---

So, what should you do here?  If your intent is to make a test for `b` distinguish between `p1` and `p3`, then your `p3` type should make that clear:

```
type p3 = { a: string, b?: undefined }; // p3 cannot have a defined "b" property
```

Now the `p4` type is, [as of TypeScript 3.2+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants), a true discriminated union.  And so this is an error:

```
let demo: p4 = { a: '123', b: '123' } // error now
```

And makes the unsound `'b'` test show up as an error.  If you want to do a "good" `b` test, you can now test for `obj.b !== undefined`, which will definitely distinguish between a `p1` and `p3` with the new `p3` definition:

```
function func(obj: p4) {
    if ('b' in obj) {
        obj.a.toFixed() // error now
    }

    if (obj.b !== undefined) {
        obj.a.toFixed(); // okay
    }
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBGCMUF4oG8oEMBcUB2BXAtgEYQBOANFIVgM7AkCW2A5lAL4CwAUKJDAMyIU6GnUYsO3cNDAAWQXCgAffly4BjAPbZaUACYR8G+ElSYoAclgAmPuYpUL122wDc6rTv2GrWMAKReRi5QAPQhOBpQpCQaJKqcXNho+BDUYGhq0ABi9AAeKPFQRVA80sZCZnhEpPYiDMyuXMUlUvyCpnVi9gD8WLjY+gBmjBC6rqHhflBqaNjYGsBQABZoAG7QaHoQw9ijUABEhPswMZAkoM1NxaUwckgKyn5unM0ANhCLgb53FViWNnZKH8nOY2BMoiQYiQIgB3QrFQb9NTAehaKCI7BqAAUGkIACtvgBKAovZrFeiDKBY8yEUGMKC4vHE5BXMlkxkAOjQHOAGhyuVGWOJYQhUNhrLJEglzQpVM5hCgAEIEEh+kMRrpmdK2Qz8VyeXy8oLCcERRoANZoEDaooSZp2hFIrGBQnxVhAA)

Comment: Hey, @jcalz nice answer! Why do you think excessive property check is performed when changing `a: number` to `a: boolean`?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBMCMUF4oG8BQUNQIYC4oDsBXAWwCMIAnAbnU1LwGdgKBLfAcxoF8oAfFWhlxQmrDtxqoA9FIIB7KJQpyKqAMZz8TKABMIxObDxxEAzNjwByWACYAzJYA0gqPSiWsDHU9RdJoSBgbUzRzYVI5OQAbCCx8GnM3UTZOXz4zTGFk8V9JGUUKZVV1TW09AxtjYKRQzKtbB2dEq09vZz8gA

Comment: `boolean` is actually defined as `true | false`, each of which is a unit type (only one value inhabits the type).  That’s enough for the compiler to see it as a discriminated union.

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom type guard function to narrow types down instead of `'b' in obj`

```
    if (!isP3(obj)) {
        obj.a.toFixed() // Error
    } else { 

    }
}
```

About the assignment `let demo: p4 = { a: '123', b: '123' }` it bothers me too that no error is given. As I found out it will work properly (which means giving an error) if we define `a` as a boolean instead of a number. Looks like the assignment fails only if the discriminator type contains union type itself. You can subscribe to this issue for details https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35861

Section of the spec on the matter doesn't explain fully the current behavior. Looks like for an explanation one have to peek into the compiler itself.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#34-union-types